# process.env doesn't work - without it's working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, get

I try to use an .env but it's not working.

[image: screenshot folder]

`` const url = `https://website&access_token=${process.env.INSTAGRAM_KEY}`; // doesn't work ``
`REACT_APP_INSTAGRAM_KEY` neither

I tried the token on my url and it's working. Therefore I know, I have to write something different.

*Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'S', "Sorry, thi"... is not valid JSON*

I know, I should place the .env in the backend, just for practise it's in the frontend :)

Comment: do you have a package that loads the `.env` file?

Comment: i don't think so ... npm i dotenv ?

Comment: @DanielA.White i missed the package ^^

Comment: @OlegBrazhnichenko . now it's working: .env: `REACT_APP_INSTAGRAM_KEY=12345...`

Answer (score 0):

I had to install a package

npm i dotenv

.env file:

````
REACT_APP_INSTAGRAM_KEY= IGQ...wdy```

var:
````

const url = `https://website&access_token=${process.env.REACT_APP_INSTAGRAM_KEY}`;```